# Accessing value of function in multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

tl;dr: How do I reuse the first function in other functions? It keeps returning undefined if called in other functions.

I create online help (I'm not a programmer), which unfortunately is output in framesets by Adobe RoboHelp. I would like to use the first function below (getURL) to dynamically build a URL that can be reused in other functions. For example, passing the "a" argument as a graphic in one function, or using it to send the page in the frameset as a mailto: link in another function.

The problem I'm having is that calling the getURL function from within other functions; the fullURL value is being returned as undefined.

```
function getURL(a) {
    var frameURL = window.frames[1].frames[1].document.location, 
    frameareaname = frameURL.pathname.split('/').slice(4, 5), 
    frameprojname = frameURL.pathname.split('/').slice(6, 7),
    protocol_name = window.location.protocol,
    server_name = window.location.host,
fullURL = protocol_name + '//' + server_name + '/robohelp/robo/server/' + frameareaname + '/projects/' + frameprojname + '/' + a;
return fullURL;
}
```

If I call the function like this, it works fine, but not if I place it inside a function:

```
 getURL('light_bulb.png');
 console.log(fullURL);
```

How can I reuse this function in another function? For example, fullURL should be the background image:

```
  $('.Graphic, .GraphicIndent, .Graphic3rd, .Graphic4th').not('.Graphic-norollover').mouseover(function()
  {
    var imgWidth = $(this).children('img').width();
    $(this).css('background', 'url(' + fullURL + ') 50% 50% no-repeat #000');
    $(this).css('width', imgWidth);
    $(this).children('img').fadeTo(750, '.4');
    $(this).children('img').attr('alt', 'Click to view full-size graphic');
    $(this).children('img').attr('title', 'Click to view full-size graphic');
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want `console.log(getURL('light_bulb.png'));`

Answer (score 3):

`fullURL` is what is returned from `getURL`, so call that function when you need the values:

```
var imageURL = getURL('some_image.png');
```

`fullURL` doesn't exist outside of `getURL`.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to work in my testing. Guess I'll try again; I think the frames are making it extra difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the function in order to be able to use it:

```
  $('.Graphic, .GraphicIndent, .Graphic3rd, .Graphic4th').not('.Graphic-norollover').mouseover(function()
  {
    var imgWidth = $(this).children('img').width();
    $(this).css('background', 'url(' + getURL('light_bulb.png') + ') 50% 50% no-repeat #000');
    $(this).css('width', imgWidth);
    $(this).children('img').fadeTo(750, '.4');
    $(this).children('img').attr('alt', 'Click to view full-size graphic');
    $(this).children('img').attr('title', 'Click to view full-size graphic');
  });
```

The `fullURL` is limited to the scope of the `getURL` function. It's not visible anywhere else. You have to call `getURL` to get the result of the function.

Comment: _Thanks_, I knew I had to call the function somewhere, just couldn't figure out where! This seems to work.